# Python3.6's Pip Checking wrong Python Version

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, python, python3, pip

I've recently upgraded to use Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. Now I have Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6 all on the same system.  I've had pip (defaults to v2.7), and pip3 (defaults to v3.5), and I then reinstalled pip3 according to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254088/3123703 .

I'm now on the path to installing all the libraries I'm using for the new Python 3.6. But for some reason, pip3.6 is checking for the libraries in Python 3.5 folders:

```
$ sudo pip3.6 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Also:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$ pip3.6 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Is there a way to get pip3.6 to not look in the Python 3.5 folders? Or do I have to completely uninstall Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 and start from scratch?

FYI, I'm not asking for a specific package, as numpy was just an example here.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982880/directing-python-to-look-in-another-folder-for-modules

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting your question:

> Is there a way to get pip3.6 to not look in the Python 3.5 folders? Or do I have to completely uninstall Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 and start from scratch?

I recommend *not* installing several different Python versions on the *system* level, instead use a dedicated tool for Python. I use Anaconda, which is great for scientific computing. Other tools exist.

## How to use a Python installation from your home directory

- You install the Python version you want to use in a separate directory (for example `~/anaconda3`)
- Add the binary folder from your Python install first in your `PATH`.

## How to handle multiple Python versions with Anaconda

1. Install Miniconda from https://conda.io/miniconda.html
2. Make sure `conda` is availible from your shell by adding the binary install folder to your `PATH`
3. Install any Python versions you want. Refer to it later with the -n parameter (`python2` or `python3` here).

   - Python 2: `conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda`
   - Python 3: `conda create -n python3 python=3.6 anaconda`
4. Switch Python version by sourcing the `activate` script

   - Python 2: `source activate python2`
   - Python 3: `source activate python3`

## Example usage

```
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % conda env list
# conda environments:
#
python2                  /home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python2
python3                  /home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python3

teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % source activate python2
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % which python
/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python2/bin/python
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__
'/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
>>> 
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % source activate python3
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % which python
/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python3/bin/python
teodorlu@XPS13 ~ % python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__
'/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to get this to work for the past hour.  It installed quite well, but when running `conda create -n python3.6 python=3.6 anaconda --file requirements.txt`, conda doesn't appear to be able to find most of the packages. Out of the 10 I've tried, I get the response `Package missing in current linux-64 channels: <package name>`. This package list comes straight from `pip3.5 freeze > requirements.txt` because I would like the same packages as in Python 3.5.

Comment: I'd try to install anaconda 3.5 first, and see if you find the package then. If that doesn't work, you can try [Virtualenvs](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Anaconda is tailored to scientific Python, whereas Virtualenv is generic.